# Probability of Picking 4 Specific Values out of 6

Tags: probability

Say you have six values (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6). Four of the values are "1", the other two are "0". You randomly pick exactly five of them. What are the odds that you pick all four 1's and one 0?

An example set could be [1 0 0 1 1 1]

My best guess would be 1/6 chance, based on a C(6,5) combination, but I'm not 100% sure that's the correct way to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I've added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six equiprobable ways to choose five values (just consider the one you leave out), but two of them are admissible (you leave out one zero).  The probability is therefore $\frac26=\frac13$